# Get the selected value in dropdown in a particular column of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the value of selected element in a dropdown in a column of datatable. Following is my code :

```
function getstate(item) {
    var rows = $("#content_objects_table").dataTable().fnGetNodes();

    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
         // Get HTML of 3rd column (for example)
        console.log("item:"+item+" id:"+$(rows[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html());
        if($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html()==item){
            console.log($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(4)").div.select.data-state);
            return ($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(4)").html());
        }   
    }
};
```

So far I am able to get the value of column having the dropdown. So I am getting a div like below:

```
<div class="selectorContainer assemblyCompleted" style="padding-left: 15px;">
    <select class="states" style="width: 150px;" data-objectid="Scorm123" data-state="ready-for-publishing">
        <option value="ready-for-publishing">Ready for Publishing</option>
        <option value="published">Published</option>
        <option value="rework">Rework</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How to get the value of selected option which is the value of data-state i.e. here data-state is "ready-for-publishing" and the value corresponding to it is Ready for Publishing.

Comment: forgot to add div pattern: <div class="selectorContainer assemblyCompleted" style="padding-left: 15px;"><select class="states" style="width: 150px;" data-objectid="Scorm123" data-state="ready-for-publishing"><option value="ready-for-publishing">Ready for Publishing</option><option value="published">Published</option><option value="rework">Rework</option></select></div>

Comment: solved myself using $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(4) div option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
/* cache row so don't keep creating new object*/
var $row=$(rows[i]);

if($row.find("td:eq(1)").html()==item){
       var state=$row.find("td:eq(4) select.states").data('state');
       var optionText=$row.find('option[value="'+state+'"]').text();

}
```